# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'eso' of null

Tags: angular

I am using App_Initializer to call one service. In my app.module.ts provider section, I've 2 App_Initializers like below:

//app.module.ts

```
{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (config: AppConfig) => () => config.load(),
    deps: [AppConfig],
    multi: true
},
{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (config: AntiforgeryService) => () => config.Load(),
    deps: [AntiforgeryService, GlobalService],
    multi: true
}
```

//Load method looks like as below in AntoforgeryService

```
Load(): Promise<any> {
        var date = new Date();
        var sourceDate = date.getDate() + "*" + date.getDay() + "%" + date.getFullYear();

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(this.forgeryService + '/CMMService-service/GetAntiForgeryToken', { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-XSRF-KEY', 'GCMT-' + sourceDate) })
                .map(res => res).catch((error: any) => {
                    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'TOKEN error');
                }).subscribe((configResponse: any) => {
                    this.parseTokenData(configResponse);
                    resolve(true);
                });
        });
    }

parseTokenData(data: any) {
        debugger;

        if (data!=null)
        {
            var result = JSON.parse(data.value);
            this.cookieToken = result.CookieToken;
            this.headerToken = result.HeaderToken;

            this.globalService.cookieToken = this.cookieToken;
            this.globalService.headerToken = this.headerToken;
        }
    }
```

When I am removing below section from providers in app.module.ts, then there is no issue:

```
 {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (config: AntiforgeryService) => () => config.Load(),
        deps: [AntiforgeryService, GlobalService],
        multi: true
    }
```

In my AntiforgeryService, I am also using one of the services named GlobalService.

I am also using AuthGuard, find the below AuthGuard code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { GlobalService } from '../services/GlobalService';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService, private globalService: GlobalService) {
    }

    canActivate(): boolean {
        debugger;
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("localhost") == -1) {
            return true;
        }

        return this.authService.handleAuthentication();
    }
}
```

Here in AuthGuard, we have function handleAuthentication, in this function we are using one config file to get the ESO details like below:

```
 public load() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get('../config/config.json')
                .map(res => res).catch((error: any) => {
                    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
                }).subscribe((configResponse: any) => {
                    debugger;
                    this.config = configResponse;
                    resolve(true);
                });

        });
    }
```

Can anybody suggest me what can be the issue?

Comment: I can't see anywhere in that code where you're referencing `eso`... Can you see what line the error is on?

Comment: @user184994 please check now, I have added relatively. I hope it will give you clarity now.

Comment: I still can't see anywhere where you using something like `.eso`. If you check the error message in the browser, which line is throwing the error?